# Is it impossible to allow a group of user to "Rename" a folder, but deny "Delete" the folder? (Windows 2012 Server)

Tags: windows-server-2008

I would like to allow a group of user to rename the name of folder, but cannot delete it (in Windows 2012 server environment). So far, I found:

1. from the web, I got "rename = delete the folder and create a new one", so there is no way to allow rename but deny delete by NTFS permission.
2. What I tried is when I untick the "delete" permission at advance permission settings, the "modify" permission is also disappered.

Is this really the case? There is no way to achieve through permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, this is impossible.

Renaming permissions are part of the delete permissions in NTFS, and that is by design.  In order to rename something, you have to have permission to delete it.